# I received a segmentation error when executing the code. What is the issue?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am learning C programming and trying to write code for a calculation. I get a segmentation fault when my program runs.

Where is the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{   
    int n,i,j,k; 
    int c,x[10];
    printf("Enter the number of springs ");                                 
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int f[n],s[n],A[n][n+1][n+2]; //declare my variables here

    memset(A, 0, n*n+1*n+2*(sizeof(A))); //put all to zeros

    //store datas for stiffness and strength

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    { 
        printf("Enter the stiffness of spring %d\n",i);                 
        scanf("%d",&s[i]);
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the force applied to the spring %d\n",i); 
        scanf("%d",&f[i]);
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        printf("\nforce applied in f[i] = %d",f[i]);
    }


    //computation for element 1 matrix

    for(k=1;k<=n;k++)

    for(i=1;i<=n+1;i++)

    {
        for(j=1;j<=n+2;j++)
        { 
            if(j==k||j==(k+1))
               A[k][i][j]=s[j];

            if(j==n+3)
                A[k][i][j]=f[j];
        }  
    } 

    for(k=1;k<=n;k++)
    {
        printf("\nmy n=%d matrix is\n",k);

        for(i=1;i<=(n+1);i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=(n+2); j++)
                printf("%d\t", A[k][i][j]);

                printf("\n");
        }
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a right time to learn how to use a debugger

Comment: `n*n+1*n+2*(sizeof(A))` That doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: In fact, all you really need there is `sizeof(A)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `memset(A,0,n*n+1*n+2*(sizeof(A)));`

to

```
memset( A,0,n*(n+1)*(n+2)*sizeof(int));
```

And the `for` loop intialization should be `i=0;` and condition `i<n`.

Comment: Hi. May i ask what is the difference between memset(A,0,n*n+1*n+2*(sizeof(A))); & memset( A,0,n*(n+1)*(n+2)*sizeof(int));  ?  Why sizeof(int) instead of sizeof(A) in this case?

Comment: Assuming that you want to set the values of array `A` as `0`.

`Why sizeof(int) instead of sizeof(A) in this case ?:`  Lets say integer is of `4 byte`, then `sizeof(int)` will give `4` as a result. Since `A` is an array declared as `int A[n][n+1][n+2];` therefore `sizeof(A)` will be equivalent to `n*(n+1)*(n+2)*sizeof(int)`. So to be correct you have to do either of these: 
`memset( A,0,sizeof(A));`  or `memset( A,0,n*(n+1)*(n+2)*sizeof(int));`

Comment: Difference between `memset(A,0,n*n+1*n+2*(sizeof(A)))`; & `memset( A,0,n*(n+1)*(n+2)*sizeof(int))`;: By compiler this `n*n+1*n+2*(sizeof(A))` will be evaluated as `(n*n)+(1*n)+(2*(sizeof(A)))` because `*` has higher precedence with respect to `+`. Therefore, your `memset(A,0,n*n+1*n+2*(sizeof(A)))` statement is logically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the reason of the segmentation fault is that your program tries to access the memory out of allocated range. Namely, in this line:

```
memset(A, 0, n*n+1*n+2*(sizeof(A)));
```

sizeof(A) is what you need here. When you multiply it by n, n + 1, n + 2, you order memset to change the memory that is not allocated for your program.

Answer (score 0):

I did not look through all your code but I think it will be enough to point out statement

```
memset(A, 0, n*n+1*n+2*(sizeof(A)));
```

There must be

```
memset( A, 0, n * ( n+1 ) * ( n+2 ) * sizeof( int ) );
```

Also take into account that if you defined an array as for example

```
int s[n];
```

then the valid range of indices will be `0, n-1`, So a loop can look like

```
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{ 
    printf("Enter the stiffness of spring %d\n",i);                 
    scanf("%d",&s[i]);
}
```